# How was Fuhrer King Bradley able to grow old?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

According to the FMA:B series, the homunculi aren't supposed to grow old. Moreover, all of the homunculi other than Wrath (King Bradley) could regenerate themselves. This even includes Greed, who's also a human-based homunculus. We also see in the series that during Bradley's death, his body degenerated. If he was able to grow normally then there shouldn't be such things happening to his body.

Comment: I made some edits for clarity; if I've changed the meaning of something, do feel free to make any changes back to reflect what you'd like to say.

Comment: Note that unlike the other homunculi, [Wrath does leave a body behind after he is killed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJYVu.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

King Bradley was part human and part homunculus.

He was born human and raised in a facility to train boys to rule.  They were injected with philospher stones and, in most cases, died. They could only survive if one strong soul took control of the body. Only Bradley was able to survive the process but it is unclear whether he truely did.  A philosopher's stone contains many human souls and not even Bradley knows if the one controlling his body is the same one he started with.

As his body is mostly human, it ages.

It should be noted that the only other known human to survive this is Ling who became Greed. It was clear in that case that both souls remained in Ling's body.

Comment: when Bradley got stabbed in his abdomen during the fight with Ling he couldn't regenerate but when Ling was shot in his forehead he could . How? Ling was also partly human and partly homunculus.

Comment: @RahulChatterjee: Consider Wrath's purpose. To be the Fuhrer and lead the nation (to the Promised Day). If Bradley is shown to quickly regenerate (e.g. after an assassination attempt), then **the consipracy is revealed**. But if Bradley dies, they can simply create a new Fuhrer and continue the conspiracy without arousing suspicion. Since Bradley has been tailor-made to his purpose, it stands to reason that his quick regeneration could have been disabled too, just like his immortality. Also, Wrath was quick for an old man, so maybe he only **visually** aged.